# need to calculate data from strings in bash script

Tags: string, bash, sum, sh

I have a data as shown below

```
 .bss LPP_procMailEmptyPrioLevel 1
 .idata LPP_interruptPdb 25
 .izero LPP_procGspProcessPinned 1
```

I need to calculate sum of integer(1+25+1) if LPP is matching in above data.

How to match first 3 characters(LPP) of 2nd letter?
if we have the match then i need to calculate the sum of the integers.

Here is what I've tried so far :

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
 echo "entering scripts/newscript.sh"
 
 input='/repo/testingscript.txt'
 if [[ $input =~ ^([^:]*:...)(.*)$ ]]; then
    
    printf '%s\n'  "${BASH_REMATCH[2]//?/*}"
else
    echo >&2 "String doesn't match pattern"
fi
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You are expected to show your code attempt and tell us where it failed. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In addition to what _Aserre_ wrote: You also have to specify in which form the input data is present (content of a file, bash array, bash scalar, ...). BTW, tagging the question with _bash_ **and** _sh_ does not make much sense. Make up your mind which shell you are going to use, and then use only the tag for this shell.

Comment: I am very new to bash. @Aserre

Comment: As an aside, diagnostic messages should be redirected to standard error, just like you do with the error message already. But having your scripts announce that they start is mostly just annoying. Instead, make sure any actually useful diagnostic messages include the name of the script, like `echo "$0: error message" >&2` (maybe process the value of `$0` somewhat to remove the path for improved legibility).

Answer (score 1):

Not pure bash, but `awk` makes it pretty simple:

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /^LPP/ { sum += $3 } END { print sum }' input.txt
27
```

(Note: I'm pretty new to awk, so edits are welcome.)